# How to prevent snooping by user of Mac app?

Tags: security, gdb, packet-sniffers, sniffing, sniffer

I am creating a Chromium/Electron based Mac app. The app is essentially a browser for my customers to use a web service that I have no control over. My requirement is that users of my app (who may have root access on their Mac) should not be able to view the URLs the app is visiting, and should be unable to gain access to the cookies the app is storing. Normally it is not hard to MITM yourself, or attach a debugger to an app and dump memory to see the URLs and cookies.

How can I prevent these types of leaks to the user? If it's impossible, it may be acceptable to make it very hard so that a very high level of sophistication is needed.

Comment: If you do not control the hardware (and even if you do), it is nigh impossible to prevent the exfiltration of data, merely to mitigate the risks. You are not going to be able to prevent your customers from using a packet-sniffer or debugger to gather data. It sounds like you're trying to obfuscate the fact that you do not provide the backend (which may be counter to customer expectations?). This may be within the scope of Stack Overflow, but it would good if you could provide more details/limit the scope of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your users have full control of their devices, it is not possible to securely prevent them from proxying or exploring what your client-side app does. Obfuscation would seem like an option, but in the end, the http request that leaves your app will traverse the whole OS through different layers, and your user can easily observe that, if not else then in network packets (but usually much easier).

The only way it is possible to prevent the user from knowing what's happening is if you have your own backend. The frontend app (Electron) would make a request to your backend, which in turn could make any request with any parameters without the user being aware.

Note though that your backend could still be used as a proxy or oracle just like if the user was connecting to the real service. This might or might not be a problem in your case, depending on what you actually want to achieve and why.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have the option to create a backend that is the exclusive gateway/proxy that the app talks to.  But you are right; the user can impersonate my app to make requests to the proxy as if the request was coming from the app.

Answer (score 1):

> The app is essentially a browser for my customers to use a web service that I have no control over. My requirement is that users of my app (who may have root access on their Mac) should not be able to view the URLs the app is visiting, and should be unable to gain access to the cookies the app is storing

Basically, you cannot (you could with the [appropriate infrastructure](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224170016_Secure_Virtual_Machine_Execution_under_an_Untrusted_Management_OS). But you lack that infrastructure).

Network communications can be secured, to a point, using HTTPS (if you can't even use *that*, then you're completely out of luck - users wouldn't even need root access to the Mac to sniff traffic). You need to verify the server certificate to be sure you're connecting to the correct server.

One thing you might do - effectual just against wannabes, I'm afraid - is first run a test API call on some random server and verify that the connection either fully succeeds, with the proper server identification and matching IP, if the server exists, or that it properly fails if the server never existed. Anything else would be a telltale that someone has taken over the network layer, and at that point you could connect to a different server, making different calls, and lament that the server isn't answering properly.

Strings in memory can be (air quote) protected (end air quote) by having them available only for the shortest time, and otherwise stored in a different form - you can have for example an URL and a random byte sequence with the same length, then store the sequence and the XOR of the URL and the sequence. You can then reconstruct the URL every time you need it, remembering to clear it off any app caches it might find its way into. Also, just for the lols, you can keep a baker's dozen of *different* URLs sprinkled in the clear throughout the code. A memory dump at that point will turn out nothing useful.

Files, of course, can be encrypted with any one of several schemes - the files residing on the same machine that has to know how to decode them makes all such schemes ultimately vulnerable, but there again, you can try and obfuscate things. I once stored some information in a ZIP file - but it was just the header of an encrypted ZIP file, with the appropriate directory entry block glued at the end. The data were actually just gzipped in the clear, there was no password whatsoever. The guys that tried to decode the file thought it was a [plain encrypted Zip file](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35818/are-password-protected-zip-files-secure) with the extension changed, wasted a significant amount of time with several Zip cracking tools, and ended up owing me a beer.

More than that, there is not much that can realistically be done.

A big advantage would be in outsourcing the API calls and "cookie" maintenance to an external service that *you* control, e.g. on Amazon AWS or Azure or similar. *Then* you could employ all kinds of protection schemes (for example: all outbound API calls could be stored in an opaque object, timestamped, nonced, and encrypted with your server's public key, and the responses sent encrypted with your client's unique key). Since this is relatively simple and cost-effective, it would also be my recommendation.